# Illegal instruction at "npm install * "

Tags: node.js, npm, debian

I am trying to install packages by [tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-build-a-lightweight-invoicing-app-with-vue-and-node-database-and-api#step-1-%E2%80%94-setting-up-server)

But command `npm install --save express body-parser connect-multiparty sqlite3 bluebird path umzug bcrypt` returns me error:

`Illegal instruction] \ rollbackFailedOptional: verb npm-session 8c141c478c582dd`

I tried

`npm config rm proxy
npm config rm https-proxy`

and reboot system

- npm version 6.13.7
- node version 13.9.0
- OS: Debian 10

Answer (score 1):

the following commands:

```
npm config rm proxy
npm config rm https-proxy
```

is to remove proxy settings from global NPM settings. Only use if u are using NPM behind a proxy server.

Try the follow:

```
npm cache clean --force
```

This removes the NPM cache. So, try again to run the installation of each of the packages ...

```
npm install --save express
npm install --save body-parser
npm install --save sqlite3
....
```

Comment: It did not help :( Thank you for your effort